# read an integer between two delimiter

Tags: c++

**my .txt file contains information like**

```
abc,bcd,10,20.  
cde,efg,30.  
hello,there,40
```

how can i read the last value, in this case 20,30 and 40 and it is between , and .

```
ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("myfile.txt");
    string doctor;
    for(int j=1;j<=5;j++)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i<=1; i++)
        { 
            getline(myfile,doctor,'.');

        }

        cout<<doctor<<endl;

        getline(myfile,doctor);
    }
    myfile.close();
```

*here, i am getting the whole line*

Comment: string _20 = myfile[myfile.size()-3] + myfile[myfile.size()-2];

Comment: Note that is only if you know exactly where the value is, but it seems like you are looking more towards a search functionality. Look into string functions. Look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Why do you use a `for` loop for only 1 iteration?  Seems like a waste; get rid of the loop or correct it.

Comment: In many programs, the entire record is read from the file into memory, then the record is examined.  If the record does not match the search criteria, another record is read.  A more efficient method is to read many records into memory since searching memory is faster than reading from the file.

Comment: Actually i have multiple lines of same kind @ThomasMatthews